# boolean assign inside a method to a local variable or not?

Tags: java, methods, boolean

1. It is not quite clear for me, how we use boolean inside a method and how to set it false. Usually if you use a variable inside a method, you assign it to a local variable, do you do the same for booleans or just use and change them.
2. why do we assign a local variable for an attribute by the way? what happens if we don't?
3. How to use a setter for a boolean?
4. How can I reduce now the size of the arraylist after someone borrows a book?

```
    public class Governance{
                    ArrayList<Intenger> Books=new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
                    private boolean active = true;


            public void borrowBook{
 /** does I assign active to a local variable? why do we assign attributes  
 to a local variable? what happens if we  dont?why I cant just use and 
 initialize (e.g. set a value) the  attribute as a I defined(best practices)**//
    boolean checkStatus = isActive(); //correct?

            if(Books.isEmpty()){
            //how to I set active to false (best practices)
            checkStatus = myFunction(); //correct or are there better ways to do it?
            }
                else if(!Books.isEmpty() && isActive){
                    System.out.println("You can borrow that book");

                else{
                System.out.println("You can not borrow that book");
                }


         }

            public static boolean myFunction(){
                return false;
            }

            public boolean isActive() {
                return active;
            }

            //what is a case where I use this and how?
            public void setActive(boolean active) {
            this.active = active;
            }

        }
```

Comment: `boolean` variables aren't any different from any other primitive variable. What makes you think `boolean checkStatus = isActive();` isn't correct?

Comment: but you could do `if (isActive()) { // all your code }`

Comment: I thought that I set the boolean to true and by default its false. So I could directly use them and not assign them to a variable. But I could not find an explanation why do we assign it to a local variable. That local variable exists only inside the method. What happens then to the changes of the attribute inside the methode.Same goes by an attribute e.g. int what happens if we don't and just use them directly.

Answer (score 2):

1. A `boolean` is a primitive data type. You can assign it like other primitives:
   `boolean active = true; active = false;`
   It can also be compared `active == true`
   Be used as a condition `if(active) { // do stuff }` No need to `active == true`
2. `active` in the class `Governance` has a scope that covers the whole class.
   If some other class wants to change it's value there will be a need to call `yourGovernanceInstance.setActive(false);` so we change the `active` property of this class instance to `false`.
3. See example above.

I struggle to share the code using the formatter, see [this link](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler#&togetherjs=cRnhTKER8d) to get a neat version. Below only if target link expires.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class Governance {
  // usually we write variables in lower case.
  private List<Integer> books = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  // private member. To change it's value it's best practice to call setters and getters to change the value.
  private boolean active = true;

  public void borrowBook() {
    if(books.isEmpty()){
    // I use "this" to refer to this class's method "isActive()"
    } else if(!books.isEmpty() && this.isActive()){
      System.out.println("You can borrow that book");
    } else {
      System.out.println("You can not borrow that book");
    }
  }

  public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
  }

  // You habe a class that has many Governance instances, e.g.
  // Governance myGov = new Governance();
  // myGov is no more active, so you call: myGov.setActive(false);
  public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
  }
}
```

You could also just use `else if(!books.isEmpty() && active)`.

4. Depends. Usually you `ArrayList` would contain `Book` objects in your context. You would have to identify the book someone wants to take.

   public class Book {
       private int id;
       private String title;
       private boolean active;

   ```
   public Book(int id, String title, boolean active) {
       this.id = id;
       this.title = title;
       this.active = active;
   }

   // Setters and Getters
   ```

   }

And in your `Governance` class:

```
  public boolean canBorrowBookWithId(int id) {
      Book bookToBeBorrowed = books.get(id);
      boolean canBorrow = true;
      // If book can is active, it can't be borrowed.
      if(bookToBeBorrowed.IsActive()){
        canBorrow = false;
      } else {
        // If not; set it to be and lend it out :-)  
        bookToBeBorrowed.setActive(true);
      }
      return canBorrow;
  }
```

> Side note: canBorrowBookWithId() checks if the book is available and
>   sets it's state. By measures of clean code a method would only do one
>   of these operations at a time!

You are trying to learn `Object oriented programming` it's hard to start, but eventually you'll catch on to that :-)

Comment: Is it only me or is Java code formating really akward on SO?

Comment: Side note: `canBorrowBookWithId()` checks if the book is available and sets it's state. By measures of clean code a method would only do one of these operations at a time!

Comment: -> why do we assign a local variable for an attribute (e.g. inside a method) by the way? what happens if we don't? why don't we use the instance variable?This question is not clear for me

Comment: Do you know what a construcotr is and why we use one? Setters have a similar point. You asign your local variable from outside of the object, say you stored a name in a person object and have a type. You have to change the name using a setter.